# Procedures shipped with SSISDB causing issues with Filtered Indexes

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2014

**SQL Server 2014** I believe. Procedures in `SSISDB` have `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` set to ***OFF*** for some reason, and was wondering if anyone had any frame of reference as to why this might be, and if it might be important.

Unfortunately I don't know if changing these procedures to set these to ***ON*** would be advisable, but if anyone had any ideas about that, it would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess it would be "unsupported". Whats the actual problem you're having?

Comment: Your question title suggests you suspect the setting of catalog/internal procs is causing issues with filtered indexes. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Adding a filtered index on a table would take some reporting I am from about a minute to a second or less. But some of the stored procedures shipped with SSISDB set quoted identifiers to OFF (those involved with cleaning out SSISDB history), which of course fails when they hit the table with the index. I removed the index already, but am still a little disappointed I had to do so. I was just wondering if anyone had any insights on the risk of setting that to on in those procedures, or why they may be set that way to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Best MSSQL practice is to `set it OFF`.

It will basically allow you to use reserved keywords or can contain characters not generally allowed by the Transact-SQL. i.e "select", "from", "identity" etc..

When `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF`, identifiers cannot be quoted and must follow all Transact-SQL rules for identifiers. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15)...

When `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON` (default), all strings delimited by double quotation marks are interpreted as object identifiers. Therefore, quoted identifiers do not have to follow the Transact-SQL rules for identifiers. They can be reserved keywords and can include characters not generally allowed in Transact-SQL identifiers.

**Usage of `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON`**

- when you are creating a filtered index
- when you invoke XML data type methods
- JSON source data import in database

**Permission required to change the settings**

- User requires membership in the public role

**Example**

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
CREATE TABLE "select" ("identity" INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, "order" INT NOT NULL);
```

↪To use "select" as table name, above query will get **failed** when `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER set OFF`

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
CREATE TABLE "select" ("identity" INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, "order" INT NOT NULL);
```

↪To use "select" as table name, above query will get **succeed** when `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER set ON`

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)